# Загрузка нескольких блоков в одном шаблоне

Tags: django

Есть следующий шаблон:
main.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% block block1 %}
{% endblock %}
{% block block2 %}
{% endblock %}
{% block block3 %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

На каждый блок есть своя view со своим шаблоном который наследуется от main.html, и получается при одном вызове я могу загрузить что-то одно. Есть ли возможность загрузить все три блока одновременно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

view и блоки никак между собой не связаны.
Шаблон разбивается на блоки не в зависимости от вьюх а в зависимости от структуры HTML страницы.

Вы привязываете к вьюхе шаблон, унаследованый от main.html и в нем переопределяете столько блоков из main сколько вам нужно.